# How to use @Autowired with Beanfactory

Tags: spring, autowired

I have instantiated bean container by using

```
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("ApplicationContext.xml"));
```

and I have also registered `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` using

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

but when I do this

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("emailService")
 private MessageService messageService;
```

its giving `NPE` it means Autowiring is not working with annotation, what is the problem with this? Can not I use BeanFactory with @Autowired?

Comment: That you aren't using an `ApplicationContext` but a `BeanFactory`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory.

Comment: @M.Deinum so its not possible to use `@Autowired` with BeanFactory?

Comment: Correct as that is only a `BeanFactory`.

Comment: If you're starting up the context yourself, use Spring Boot to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question there may be two solution.

1) First you need to check whether your class is annoted with like @Component,@Service

2) And you cannot call a class with new Object,you have to extract from applicationcontext only.